# Perl automatically adds newline to output file

Tags: perl

I am using Perl to write to a file. It keeps adding a newline to the output file in the same spot even after I use `chomp`. I cannot figure out why.

Sample Code (reading from an input file, processing the line and then writing that line out to the output file):

```
open(OUT, "> out.txt");
# ...
while(<STDIN>) {
    # ...
    my $var = substr($_, index($_, "as "));
    chomp($var);
    print("Var is: " . $var); # no newline
    print OUT $var . ","; # adds newline before the comma
    # ...
}
# ...
close(OUT);
```

Any ideas as to what might be causing this or how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: `substr($_, index($_, "as "))` will return the last character of `$_` if it doesn't contain `as `. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 3):

The *cannonical* procedure:

```
while(<STDIN>) {
    chomp;
    # ...
    my $var = substr($_, index($_, "as "));
    print("Var is: " . $var); # no newline
    print OUT $var . ","; # adds newline before the comma
    # ...
}
```

> In most operating systems, lines in files are terminated by newlines.
>   Just what is used as a newline may vary from OS to OS. Unix
>   traditionally uses \012 , one type of DOSish I/O uses \015\012 , Mac
>   OS uses \015 , and z/OS uses \025 .
>
> Perl uses \n to represent the "logical" newline, where what is logical
>   may depend on the platform in use. In MacPerl, \n always means \015 .
>   On EBCDIC platforms, \n could be \025 or \045 . In DOSish perls, \n
>   usually means \012 , but when accessing a file in "text" mode, perl
>   uses the :crlf layer that translates it to (or from) \015\012 ,
>   depending on whether you're reading or writing. Unix does the same
>   thing on ttys in canonical mode. \015\012 is commonly referred to as
>   CRLF.
>
> To trim trailing newlines from text lines use chomp(). With default
>   settings that function looks for a trailing \n character and thus
>   trims in a **portable way**.

In this case you're hitting a cross-platform barrier, you're reading documents written on an `os`, from a different and not compatible  platform.

For an isolated execution you should covert your file line endings to match the host.

To address the issue permanently, you can try: https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Edit::Portable . **Thanks @stevieb**

Comment: Cool, thanks. I actually figured out it was an issue with the newline in the original input file; it must have been made on a different OS. Thanks though!

Comment: If you're going to be editing many files with other line endings than the current platform, check out https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Edit::Portable

Comment: @klashxx Your answer does not provide any solution, it is addressing only a simple syntax simplification. So I can understand the downvote (but it was not me who downvoted). Posting this in a comment would have been fine.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, not if `$index == -1` -- you really want to chomp first.